# does pythons tar file finalize a file added, or wait till its closed?

Tags: python, compression, tar, filehandle

I apologize if the questions title is not clear.

I am creating a very large compressed [TarFile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#module-tarfile) using python.

I need to know if when using [`TarFile.Add()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add) does that close and/or finalize the file added, or can the file still be modified?

For instance, if I were to create an empty text file and then add it to a TarFile, and then modify the text file, and then close the TarFile, would the changes made to the text file appear in the TarFile, or is the text file added as it was at the time of the [`TarFile.Add()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add)?

Thank you.

Note: If it makes any sort of difference, the code is running on a Ubuntu machine, and the archive is also being created on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file contents **won't** get updated after you call `add()`.

See the below code:

```
import tarfile

fp1 = open("hello.txt", "w")

tar = tarfile.open("myArchive.tar", "w")
tar.add("hello.txt")

fp1.write("Test String")
fp1.close()

tar.close()
```

After this is executed, 'hello.txt' will have "Test String", but the 'hello.txt' inside 'myArchive.tar' will be empty.

Comment: thanks, this is great, you could improve your answer by including an example "read" from the file outside the archive, but thanks!